# Removing unwanted newline characters in Wygwam

Tags: add-on, fieldtype, wygwam, wysiwyg

Wygwam automatically adds some extra space in `<p>` tags by default. Is there any way to remove them without editing the source in Wygwam? I'm using Wygwam 2.6.3.

**What is intended**

```
<p>This is a paragraph</p>
```

**What actually happens**

```
<p>
     This is a paragraph</p>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The themes/third_party/wygwam/lib/ckeditor/config.js file actually comes with the code necessary to do this – you just need to uncomment it. Have you tried that?

Comment: duh, it was staring me right in the face!

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to override the default CKEditor rules for processing P tags.

Add this:

```
this.dataProcessor.writer.setRules( 'p',
                {
                    indent : false,
                    breakBeforeOpen : true,
                    breakAfterOpen : false,
                    breakBeforeClose : false,
                    breakAfterClose : true
                });
```

to your:
`themes/third_party/wygwam/lib/ckeditor/config.js` file.

More info here:
http://ckeditor.com/forums/Support/BUG-CKeditor-adds-new-line-and-tab-space-after-P-tag

Comment: hmm, I added that and it makes sense why, but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: Did you add it inside the instanceReady function?

Comment: Yep, this is what that config file looks like http://jsfiddle.net/CSHZD/

Comment: Try clearing your browser's cache?

Comment: nope :( still no luck